# How can change format date in a text field?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want change format date in a textfield in my form, but show this error

```
undefined method `strftime' for :fecha:Symbol
```

This is my code

```
<%= f.text_field :fecha.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %>
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<%= f.text_field :fecha, :value => @object.facha.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %>
```

`@object` will be the object for which you are creating a form

for eg

```
<%= form_for @object %>
```